# Custom Textarea for right to left languages

Tags: javascript, textarea

I need a custom text area inside which when the keyboard Enetr key is pressed sould insert new from right to left. and when back space is clicked at the beginning of that line shuold remove that line.

Answer (score 11):

Use `dir="rtl"` in the tag?

Comment: thanks for the reply. there is still a problem when using dir="rtl". when you press enter key for new line a new line is not entered but the line created comes down.
    i want the direction right to left to be set.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [CSS direction property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_direction.asp), `direction: rtl;`.

After reading your comment to digitalFresh... Here's the solution you're looking for:

```
<textarea style="text-align: right;"></textarea>
```